# Cookie problems with virtual directories in IIS (deleting unwanted cookies)

Tags: iis, cookies, asp-classic, virtual-directory

I've just had a small nightmare with unwanted cookies somehow being created. I swear my code never created a cookie in a certain virtual directory, it just read it, but somehow my browser ended up with a root cookie and a copy of this cookie for the vdir too. Which meant the two values were separate and did not both get updated.

Most articles about deleting cookies say to set it to blank, which is no help, as it will still exist!

I had to write a short ASP to set the cookie expiry to last year, and also make sure I specified the path as the vdir in question, to make sure it killed the one I didn't want.

```
Response.Cookies("BWWF2")("UID") = ""
Response.Cookies("BWWF2").Path = "/community"
Response.Cookies("BWWF2").Expires = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Now())
```

Hopefully this has solved the problem, but I wanted to share this here, and also ask if anyone has a better way to solve the issue, or any ideas on how the problem (two cookies) might have happened in the first place?!

Comment: Has community been accidentially marked as a application?

Comment: I think the virtual directory was unintentionally set as an Application in IIS for a time, yes. However, I swear that no code in the 'community' folder ever wrote the UID cookie, only read it....

Answer (score 1):

You should check you IIS settings on those virtual directorys, and set the Application name to "Default Application"

You will get a new cookie and sessionId when entering a Virtual Direcotry if the Application name is different then the rest of the site.